# Why are the words for "children" (liberi) and "book" (libri) so similar?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, etymology, word-comparison

While working in class, I came across this. They have a similar spelling, yet mean completely different things. Is this just random or does it have an actual purpose in the Latin language?

- Book = *Libri*
- Children = *Liberi*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These words are unrelated: they developed independently from different Proto-Indo-European roots, according to Michiel de Vaan's *Etymological Dictionary* (337–38).

First, *liber* or *librī*, meaning "book," is thought to come from a PIE word meaning "leaf, rind": **lubʰ-ro-*.  De Vaan cites several Indo-European languages that have attested cognates and summarizes:

> We may surmise that *liber* is cognate with **lubʰ-* and goes back to a PIE word or a European word 'leaf, rind'.

On the other hand, *līber*, meaning "children," comes from a different PIE word (**h<sub>1</sub>leudʰ-ero-*), through a Proto-Italic word **leuþ-ero*.  The word also means "free," and the "children" meaning developed later.  De Vaan explains again:

> The change of the pl. *līberī* to 'children' is explained by Benveniste from legal terminology, in which the legitimate 'children' of a free couple were denominated as 'free ones'.

So it's simply a coincidence that these words ultimately came to look very similar: they developed from distinct PIE roots.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the parent speech provenance reflects in the short *i* in *lĭber* the child (*u > proto-Italic *i) but long *i* in *līber* the book (from the diphthong *eu > *ī). These were simply two different sounds for a pre-classical and classical Latin speaker, not quite as similar as they are to the modern ear!

Comment: And it is almost worth noting that the English have always been famous for teaching wrong quantities. With the result that **Liber** (book) with a short **i** gives us Library with a long **i.** But **Līber** (free/child) with a long *ee* sound gives English 'liberty' with short **i**

Comment: @kkm. It is actually the other way around. "Child" has a long i, "book" has a short i.

Comment: @fdb Better later than never. Thanks, of course I switched them around.